# TortoiseSVN: color of the folder disappeared after re-checking out; resolving conflict

Tags: svn, colors, tortoisesvn, conflict

1) I got some conflicts when updating one of my working copies.  I struggled to resolve the conflict but failed miserably, then I decided to just remove the .svn folder and re-checkout from the repository.  After that the color of the working copy folder disappeared (i.e, no green check marks at all), although I can still do svn update, svn commit, etc.  I'm on Windows 7 Home.

2) I still have conflicts on another working copy.  The warning message is as follows:

Trying to change property 'svn:ignore'
but the property has already been locally changed to a different value.
Local property value:
file1
file2
file3
file4

Incoming property value:
file1
file3
file4
file5

How should I resolve this conflict?

3) If I decide to re-checkout, what is the proper procedure to do that?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What is your subversion client application? Subclipse? In other words, what is the application that is marking files with or without the green check marks, etc.?

Comment: Yes TortoiseSVN.  Just updated the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any changes in your working copy that you need to save or if your changes are minimal, then your best bet is to:

1) Rename the directory that your existing working copy is in (i.e. WC Old)

2) Create a new folder with the same name as the one you just renamed

3) Right-click on the new folder and select SVN Checkout...

Follow the steps from here that you used to check out the source initially.

If you have a lot of changes in your working copy and you know the folder that the issue is occurring in, you can:

1) Right click on the folder and select Tortoise SVN and then Revert...

2) VERY CAREFULLY, ensure that ONLY the folder icon (this is the location that the ignore values are stored) is checked.

3) Click Ok.

This will revert just the changes on the folder itself, which is where the ignore values are stored.

If you are incredibly brave, you could also display the properties for the folder in windows explorer, click the subversion tab, click the properties button, and edit or remove the properties as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the help competent_tech.  The revert trick worked well and solved my problem with the second working copy.  I thought of doing that but was afraid to try.  

Now back to the color question: the thing is there are many files/folders in the WC directory, some are versioned, some are not and/or ignored.  I could do what you described by getting the versioned file/folders first then add everything else manually, but is there any easier way?

Comment: The issue is going to be why the colors are missing and there are basically two things that happen here: 1) if the root folder no longer thinks it is under version control, usually due to the loss or corruption of the .svn folder, then you will never see colors because it isn't versioned; 2) there are many transient cases where explorer and tortoise get out sync. The 2nd one can usually be resolved by F5ing (refreshing) the folder or closing explorer, but sometimes it takes a reboot. The first issue can sometimes be fixed by selecting the directory right-clicking and choosing SVN update.

Comment: I did restart the computer, didn't solve the problem.  Today I restarted again, now the color's back.  Thank you!

Comment: That's excellent news. Since this resolved the issue for you, can you click the checkbox next to the answer to let others know that this worked for you? Thanks!

Comment: Done!  Sorry for being late.  I'm not familiar with the etiquette.

Comment: Does not work for me and I am in no mood to restart now. Windows 7-64b, tortoise svn 1.8, visual svn 3.x all 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Run a clean-up, it will solve most icon overlay issues.

Comment: can you please put the GUI and/or commandline steps for doing a clean-up ?

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN > Settings > Icon Overlays >  Change "Status cache" from "default" to "shell".

Happy development ;)

Comment: This does not work for me. What does this step actually do and where did you learn it ?